# Need two environments in table

Tags: tables, environments, typography

I want to set up a table with the column headings centered, but the data right justified, without using `\multicolumn` for every single cell in the heading, rather I want to use a locally global typesetting default.  I tried two separate `\tabular` environments, and Latex put the two tables side by side, not one underneath the other.  I would also use an environment specification that had to come before every line. Any ideas?

Comment: For colum header you can define own comand, something as ˛\newcomand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}` or use macro `\thea` from package `makecell` etc. Of course you still need to write `\mc{...}` or `\thead{...}` in columns heading. To be more specific you need prowide a minimal working example (MWE) which show, what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `makecell` package defines a `\thead` command that is by default vertically and horizontally centred, and allows for a common formatting and linebreaks inside these cells.

Comment: @Mico: Of course it was `make  eel`  since it was a `pzackage` :o)

Comment: @Bernard your `pzackage` is full of eels ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: My hovercraft …

Answer (score 2):

Having to type

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ ... }
```

repeatedly to center-set each header cell is certainly tedious. However, setting up a shortcut macro, e.g., via

```
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
```

and then writing `\mc{ ... }` in each header cell should be manageable, unless your table has a very large number of columns.

For sure, typing a few `\mc` directives must be faster and less overhead-intensive than creating two separate `tabular` environments -- one for the header row and one for the remaining rows -- and then having to ensure that the column widths match up across all columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\mc{H1} & \mc{H2} & \mc{H3} & \mc{H4} & \mc{H5} \\[1ex]
11111111 & 22222222 & 33333333 & 44444444 & 55555555 \\
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```